# Is there a way to use a MySQL trigger to duplicate a record in a table, but modify the data before insert?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update

I am applying a series of triggers to a few tables in our database - these will serve the purpose of creating soft-delete/shadow records when certain *relevant* data is updated.

An example, consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_content` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='                   ';
```

**Using this query**

```
UPDATE cms_content SET `tag` = 'user-cities-field' WHERE id = 3;
```

When this query is executed, I want to essentially perform the following manipulations:

- Set the INSERT `id` of the incoming record to NULL, so that `AUTO_INCREMENT` will set the next value accordingly.
- Insert a copy of the record that was *updated*, with the only modification being that the `is_active` flag needs to get set to `1`
- I know that you cannot update the table from within here as MySQL will block it to prevent recursion.
- If there is a way, can you essentially select the record being updated, prior to being updated, and then `INSERT` the modified record?

Would it be more useful to use a stored function to handle this?

What I **need** to do is to select the OLD record `pre-update`, and then change the value of the `is_active` flag on that record before it is inserted. The code I have been working with is below.

**Trigger**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `cms_content_AFTER_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `cms_content` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.is_active = 1) THEN

        SET NEW.id = NULL;

        INSERT INTO `tester`.`cms_content` (SELECT *, 0 as is_active  from `cms_content` WHERE `id` = OLD.`id`);
        #UPDATE      `tester`.`cms_content` SET is_active = 0 WHERE `id` = OLD.`id`;

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: You are correct that  'MySQL will block it to prevent recursion' and there is no way round that using a trigger. Why not create a cms_content_history table which can be maintained with triggers on cms_content. I don't think the overhead of joins/unions would be onerous.

Comment: @P.Salmon I need to be able to create shadow records / soft-deleted records in the current table. Is that possible?